# UserControl in Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

In my application I use Caliburn.Micro to bind between View and ViewModel. In one of my view I want use CrystalReportsViewer user control but I dont know how to do it. First I try something like this (cr is allias for SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer)

```
<Grid>
    <cr:CrystalReportsViewer x:Name="Viewer" />
</Grid>
```

My View display Viewer, but how to bind this control to my ViewModel? I want access to my viewer from my viewmodel to display report.
I use property but that not working(and have no sense).
So my next idea was using ContentControl

```
<Grid>
    <ContentControl x:Name="Viewer" />
</Grid>
```

but now Caliburn search for ViewModel.
I allways may use CodeBehind but I dont want. Maybe someone who has experiance with caliburn.Micro and usercontrol can help.

Comment: make a ViewModel + View for your "Viewer" and place your crystal Report Viewer in it. As you said caliburn is looking for exaktly that viewmodel.

Comment: But how to access to Viewer from datamodel?

Comment: Create a ViewModel : MyCrystalRepViewModel ... and a View : MyCrystalRepView .... than just make a Property in your Main viewmodel named "Viewer" of type MyCrystalRepViewModel  ... and instanciate it. In MyCrystalRepView put your `<cr:CrystalReportsViewer`

Comment: let MyCrystalRepViewModel inherit from `Screen'

Comment: I know how to do that, but I dont know how to in my ViewModel do something like that `Viewer.ViewerCore.ReportSource = new MyReport();`

Comment: Create a Property `ReportSource` and bind it to your Viewer like `<cr:CrystalReportsViewer ResportSource={Binding ReportSource}" ... `

Comment: Thanks but i cannot access to ResportSource so i use Message.Attach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Message cal:Message.Attach="[Event Loaded] = [Action LoadReport($this)]" and that is all I need